# MAMP Not Displaying localhost:8888 on Mac

Tags: apache, localhost, mamp

I've used MAMP for many years and have always been going to http://localhost:8888 to get a quick index of folders and files.

Not sure what has changed, but now no matter what version of MAMP I run, I'm not able to get my index of files in my browser... When starting servers I'm able to see that both the Apache and MySQL are green and I can even reach the WebStart page at http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English

How can I get to this index so I can test my sites in the "user/documents/ sites" document root I've setup? When I go to http://localhost:8888 the page just keeps loading and never actually loads anything.

I've set the Apache Port to 8888 and MySQL to 3306 -- any other settings won't work at all.

Comment: This problem has come back and the solution I mentioned below no longer works. When I just use "localhost" in the browser's URL bar, I get a blank white page that says "It works!" But now how do I get to the htdocs folder where I've put all my sites locally?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of http://localhost:8888 try your local ip address. Sometimes "localhost" doesn't work.

For the long run either install or local dns server or modify you 'host' file in /etc - you will need a fixed local ip address for this.

Peter

Comment: I found that if I switch to port to 8887 then I'm able to connect using http://localhost:8887 however the page will only load when I use the default MAMP /htdocs folder. If I use a custom folder the directory won't load.

Also, trying to just our local IP like http://localhost:10.0.1.1/ doesn't work either.

Comment: Joe,
This will not work: 'localhost:10.0.1.1'

Try: 'http://10.0.1.1:8887' instead.

Peter

Comment: Thanks, Peter. But this still does not work for me. Going to 10.0.1.1:8887 just loads forever with the page saying "Connecting to 10.0.1.1..." but never actually loading anything and eventually timing outI

I have my Apache Port set to 8887, Nginx set to 7888, and MySQL as 8889

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I would recommend going into your command line and type "ipconfig" and you should get your IPv4 which will return your IP address "172.31x.xx.xxx". After finding that, you should go to your File setting in Brackets and then go to your project settings and type in the URL `http://172.xx.xx.xxx/`.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just open **MAMP Application**,then go to **MAMP preferences** then go to **Ports** then change the *Apache Port* to **8887** (you can give **1 - 65535** any value ) then click Ok after that Click the **start server** button after that it will works fine.